Оператор ! и проверки
Что означает оператор ! перед isFinite и isNaN
P.s Я понимаю что оператор ! значит отрицание(not), условно !=, значит, "не равно"
Но как правильно прочитать его с этими проверками, типо как мы можем это произнести в слух
isНомер типо так?

is - обычно указывает на булевское значение, т.е. является ли значение/объект/... чем-то. Обычно условия должны быть истины, так их проще воспринимать: if apple.isRed() - если яблоко красное. Но также нужно выражать и отрицание: if !apple.isRed() - Если яблоко НЕ красное. А вообще, так любят сокращать булевские сравнения if apple.isRed() == true или if apple.isRed() == false

Я не знаток JavaScript, поэтому если где-то ошибаюсь, прошу поправить. Но вообще просто берём и читаем по словам. Ну и отрицание отрицания даёт утверждение.



Название или выражение
Как читать




is
Является


Finite
Конечное число


NaN
Не число


isFinite
Является конечным числом


isNaN
Является не-числомилиНе является числом


!
Не


!isFinite
Не является конечным числомилиЯвляется бесконечным числом


!isNaN
Не является не-числомилиЯвляется числом



